How do I find formula used in html calculator
I have searched and unable to find formula for this calculator.
https://www.saltyunderground.com/support/berghia-calculator.html
Open source page and locate formula then use to create custom calculator.
I was told I need to:
To create this calcaultor you would need a Numeric Input field element, Select Field element and a Formula I need assistance in finding the formula.
Thank you in advance,
td

Formula? What formula?

Here it is:
function berghiaCalc(form) {


var numBerghiaGal = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,250,300,400,500,600];
var numBerghia = [  [2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,10,15,15,18],
                        [4,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,12,15,18,22,25,28],
                        [6,8,10,10,12,14,16,16,18,20,24,25,30,35,40],
                        [8,10,12,14,18,18,20,20,22,25,30,35,40,45,50] 
                    ];
    numBerghiaEntries = 14;
    gallonTank = eval(form.gallonTank.value);
    berghiaLevelInfestation = eval(form.berghiaLevelInfestation.value);
    
    switch(berghiaLevelInfestation) {
        case 1:
            berghiaUnits = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            berghiaUnits = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            berghiaUnits = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            berghiaUnits = 3;
            break;
        default:
            berghiaUnits = -1;
    }
    
    if (gallonTank == null || gallonTank < 1) {
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "Please enter the Gallons in Tank";
    } else if (berghiaUnits == -1) {
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "Please select an Infestation Level";
    } else {
        // numberBerghia=Math.round((gallonTank / 20) * berghiaUnits);
        
        i = 0;
        while ((i <= numBerghiaEntries) && (numBerghiaGal[i] < gallonTank)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i > numBerghiaEntries) {i = numBerghiaEntries;}
        numberBerghia = numBerghia[berghiaUnits][i];
    
        form.berghianeeded.value = numberBerghia;
        form.berghianeeded.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "";
    }
}

Emphasis is on the while cycle and the if along with the assignment afterwards. Here you can test it in action:


function berghiaCalc(form) {


var numBerghiaGal = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,250,300,400,500,600];
var numBerghia = [  [2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,10,15,15,18],
                        [4,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,12,15,18,22,25,28],
                        [6,8,10,10,12,14,16,16,18,20,24,25,30,35,40],
                        [8,10,12,14,18,18,20,20,22,25,30,35,40,45,50] 
                    ];
    numBerghiaEntries = 14;
    gallonTank = eval(form.gallonTank.value);
    berghiaLevelInfestation = eval(form.berghiaLevelInfestation.value);
    
    switch(berghiaLevelInfestation) {
        case 1:
            berghiaUnits = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            berghiaUnits = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            berghiaUnits = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            berghiaUnits = 3;
            break;
        default:
            berghiaUnits = -1;
    }
    
    if (gallonTank == null || gallonTank < 1) {
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "Please enter the Gallons in Tank";
    } else if (berghiaUnits == -1) {
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "Please select an Infestation Level";
    } else {
        // numberBerghia=Math.round((gallonTank / 20) * berghiaUnits);
        
        i = 0;
        while ((i <= numBerghiaEntries) && (numBerghiaGal[i] < gallonTank)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i > numBerghiaEntries) {i = numBerghiaEntries;}
        numberBerghia = numBerghia[berghiaUnits][i];
    
        form.berghianeeded.value = numberBerghia;
        form.berghianeeded.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('berghiaFormError').innerHTML = "";
    }
}
<form>
    <span id="berghiaFormError"></span>
    <input class="berghia-form-field" type="text" name="gallonTank" id="gallonTank">
    <select class="berghiaLevelInfestation" id="berghiaLevelInfestation" name="berghiaLevelInfestation" title="Infestation">
            <option value="0">Select...</option>
            <option value="1">Light</option>
            <option value="2">Moderate</option>
            <option value="3">Heavy</option>
            <option value="4">Extreme</option>
    </select>
  <input class="berghia-form-field-disabled" style="visibility: visible;" type="text" name="berghianeeded" id="berghianeeded" disabled="">
  <input class="berghia-submit-button" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="berghiaCalc(this.form);">
</form>



